# Populating a table using XSL to filter based on criteria

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

Fairly new to XSL transformations, but have been searching Stack overflow for a few hours and can't quite achieve what I'm going for. I have an xml document that I want to turn in to a table via an xsl stylesheet, but I want to select only specific pars of the XML based on the values of the nodes. Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="guitarsXSLStyleSheet.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<guitars>
    <guitar>
        <model>Strat</model>
        <year>1978</year>
        <price>2500</price>
    </guitar>
    <guitar>
        <model>Jaguar</model>
        <year>2006</year>
        <price>400</price>
    </guitar>
    <guitar>
        <model>Strat</model>
        <year>2015</year>
        <price>900</price>
    </guitar>
    <guitar>
        <model>Tele</model>
        <year>1981</year>
        <price>1200</price>
    </guitar>
</guitars>
```

Now I have an xsl stylesheet, which outputs this all to a table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table id="guitarTable" border="1" width="200">
            <tr class="header">
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//guitar"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="guitar">
        <tr>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="model" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="year" />  </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="price" /> </td>

        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, let's say I'm trying to generate a table which would only show all columns for the Strats, but the Strats only. How would I do that?

I thought maybe changing the line `<td> <xsl:value-of select="model" /> </td>`

to

`<td> <xsl:value-of select="model[text()='Strat']" /> </td>`

would do it, but it still gives me a table 4 rows long, with just the non-matching model columns blanked out, but the rest still shows. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<xsl:apply-templates select="//guitar"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="//guitar[model = 'Strat']"/>`. Note that trying to learn XSLT and XPath by reading StackOverflow answer can help but any basic XPath tutorial as a starting point is probably a better way.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I've definitely been reading the tutorials I can get my hands on, but couldn't find any where it dealt with inserting this and applying it to a table. Quick follow up, is there a way to get this to work with just a partial match? Such as: `<xsl:apply-templates select="//guitar[model = 'Str']"/> `